# pandas groupby adding sliced out elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Is this a bug? I have a dataframe `df`, which I slice with

```
df2 = df[df.user_id=='10122']
```

Then I ask for an aggregate:

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['user_id','date']).agg({'amount':sum})
```

But `df3` has elements with `user_id != '10122'`.
Is this a bug, or me doing something wrong?

Here is a sample of the dataframe per questions in comments:

```
       index            user_id unique_transaction_id  amount  date
271  2639960  99XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 151XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   29.36  2019-01-02
566  2664779  99XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 334XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   14.29  2019-01-02
```

Comment: Can post sample data of the dataframe?